# Search and replace to merge or eliminate text lines

Tags: microsoft-windows, search, text-editing, replace, newlines

A WinRAR command (*rar vt -pmypassword -v myarc.part01.rar >source.txt*) produces detailed information on files contained in .rar files or segments (e.g., filename.part01.rar). Here's an example for one such file:

```
       Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt
       Type: File
       Size: 213
Packed size: 112
      Ratio: 52%
   Modified: 2022-12-16 19:46:23,000000000
    Created: 2022-12-31 06:56:42,887343500
 Attributes: I.A....
     BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
    Host OS: Windows
Compression: RAR 5.0(v50) -m2 -md=256M
      Flags: solid encrypted
```

In this case, source.txt contains a vast number of such entries. That is, for each of many files, I have 12 similar lines of data.

For each such file, I would like to convert those many lines into a single line containing the Name, Type, and BLAKE2 lines, caret-delimited. Sample output:

```
Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt^Type: File^BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
```

Notes: (1) There are eight blank spaces before "Name" in source.txt, and the colons in the other rows in source.txt are vertically aligned with the colon in "Name:". Superfluous spaces will ideally be removed from the resulting line. (2) In some cases, it is "Type: Folder" instead of "Type: File." (3) For the record, those are BLAKE2sp hashes, not BLAKE2.

Unless there is an easier way in Emacs, I can use repeated commands like `grep -v "pattern" source.txt > target.txt; mv target.txt source.txt` to eliminate each type of unwanted line (e.g., all occurrences of the Modified line) throughout the file.

That leaves me with the three lines containing the desired information, like this:

```
       Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt
       Type: File
     BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
```

My question is how to convert those to a single line. I was thinking I would replace all occurrences of "line break plus eight spaces plus Type:" to ^Type:, and then I would do something similar with all occurrences of "line break plus six spaces plus BLAKE2:".

I'm using GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32). For the search-and-replace operation that would put ^Type: onto the Name: line, I think I have the Search part working: *Ctrl-S > Enter > Ctrl-W > Ctrl-Q > Ctrl-J > "        Type: " (i.e., eight spaces, then Type:, then another space, without quotation marks)*. But I can't figure out how to enter the Replace part.

Comment: If you work with lists, then you can extract anything you want from the list and create your own output, whether that be one line per file separating data by delimiters, or anything else.  E.g., `'((name . abc) (type . def) (file . ghi))`  The entire rar output in the example can easily be converted into a list, and the master list can multiple lists, one for each file:  `'(((name . abc) (type . def) (file . ghi)) ((name . jkl) (type . mno) (file . pqr)))`

Comment: Emacs is the wrong tool for such manipulations. You can contort it into a tool whose capabilities are poor relatives of what an appropriate tool provides, but why if the tool already exists? If you massage the file to have an empty line between records, you could write an `awk` script to do what you want in half a dozen lines of code - maybe fewer. That's because `awk` was *made* for such tasks. I know you say that you don't know `awk` but maybe you should learn it (particularly if you have more questions like this in the future).

Answer (score 2):

I know that you are looking for an Emacs solution and it may be that somebody will provide one, but that's the wrong way to go about the problem: you should use the right tool for the job. There is more to life than Emacs alone.

In this case, `awk` provides "record processing" where a "record" is a sequence of lines. In order to mark the end of the record, `awk` assumes that records are separated by an empty line. So my suggestion is to regenerate your file and add that empty line between records in order to make life easier for subsequent processing.

Given an input file like that, the following `awk` script will (almost) do what you want:

```awk
BEGIN { RS = ""; FS="\n";}
      { printf "%s^%s^%s\n", $1, $2, $9; }
```

The initialization line says the record separator `RS` has the special value `""` (the empty string). That is a signal to awk that the input file has the structure described above and each record is a sequence of lines. The field separator `FS` is set to `newline`, thus making each line into a separate field. So the `Name` line is field 1, the `File` line is field 2 and the `BLAKE2` line is field 9.

The second line describes the processing (with an implicit loop over all the records as always in `awk`). It prints fields 1, 2 and 9, separated by carets. Assuming that the script is in a file `script.awk`, you run it like this:

```shell
awk -f script.awk -- input.txt
```

On an input consisting of two copies of the record you show in your question (with one copy separated by an empty line from the next), the script gives:

```
       Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt^       Type: File^     BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
       Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt^       Type: File^     BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
```

As you can see, what the script does not do is deal with the leading white space. `awk` has functions for manipulating strings, so it is conceivable to come up with one to strip the spaces, but there is a better way. We can use `sed` to get rid of leading white space, even before `awk` gets its hands on the input. Unix notates such chaining of programs with the output of one becoming the input of the next one using the `pipe` operator `|`. Here's a `sed` command to get rid of initial whitespace:

```shell
sed 's/^ *//' input.txt
```

That can then be combined in a pipe with `awk` running the script above to do the second part:

```shell
sed 's/^ *//' input.txt | awk -f script.awk
```

and you are done. The output looks like this:

```
Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt^Type: File^BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
Name: Folder Name\Subfolder\File Name.txt^Type: File^BLAKE2: d00d0d72343d14fa2e6a4201d613df41702f8cd408527c435bb566c1cbda532a
```

I submit to you that this is a better way to do things than trying to combine Emacs interactive operations into a macro that would then have to be repeated maybe thousands of times. At the very least, it would be a slow way to deal with large inputs.

Comment: A comprehensive and lucid answer. Thank you! 

One problem: why do you suppose `awk` is giving me Flags (field no. 12) instead of BLAKE2 (field no. 9)? Haven't checked every single line of output, but scrolling suggests that is the consistent result. The output came from Windows, but I opened and saved in `gedit` using Unix/Linux line endings. Also, to get the results into a file, is it OK to just use `> output.txt`?

Comment: Output redirection works fine (at least on Linux). As for the field problem, what happens if you change the `$9` to e.g. `$8`? Do you get a different field or still `Flags`?. Try on a small portion of the input file (a few records) and post an example in your question. Even if I cannot check, somebody else might be able to. Also, add to your question as many details as you possibly can about how you run these things. Are you using WSL for the Linux layer or something else?